# Can't do pipenv install --python3.9 on VS, shows exceptions

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm a python beginner. I'm using Visual Studio Code (edited) and used to be able to do `pipenv install --python3.9` in the terminal, but now after I've done a lot of installation and stuff (by following different tutorials, trying out different stuff), I'm getting tons of exceptions:

```
Installing --python3.9...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 93, in __init__
    req = REQUIREMENT.parseString(requirement_string)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1654, in parseString
    raise exc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1644, in parseString
    loc, tokens = self._parse( instring, 0 )
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1402, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 3417, in parseImpl
    loc, exprtokens = e._parse( instring, loc, doActions )
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1402, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 3739, in parseImpl
    return self.expr._parse( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False )
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1402, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 3400, in parseImpl
    loc, resultlist = self.exprs[0]._parse( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False )
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1406, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 2711, in parseImpl
    raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)
pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing.ParseException: Expected W:(abcd...) (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

and it just goes on.

Comment: Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Visual Studio Code, sorry I didn't know there were different

Answer (score 0):

you can trying making a virtual env with
`python3 -m venv venv`
activate the virtual environment with
`venv/bin/activate`
Then try running your command .

Comment: Sorry I just fixed it but I'm talking about Visual Studio Code. I tried that but I'm still getting the same thing.